# Kolmogorov distributuon derivation

Tags: probability, distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I would like to know if there is a book talking about the derivation of Kolmogorov distribution (Using usual definition for the bridge process)
\begin{align}
P(K\leq x)=1-2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{i-1}e^{-2i^{2}x^{2}}
\end{align}
I would like to understand the achievement of final results. I search through the internet but in most cases, the result is quoted without proofs. I want to read the original version written by Kolmogorov but I cannot find it. I curious about the appearance of infinity integral and so I want to study the proof myself. Hope someone here can give me answer.

Comment: The reference is Kolmogorov A (1933) Sulla determinazione empirica di una legge di distribuzione G. Ist. Ital. Attuari. 4: 83–91.  There's an English translation in Springer's Selected Works of A. N. Kolmogorov (vol II) by Albert Shiryaev.  I haven't read it but think there's a poisson process hiding there you can get the asymptotics from.  [Not given as answer because it's more hearsay than actual knowledge ;)]  If you simply want "a" proof rather than understanding the historical development it might be easier to look at the BB results.